# HTML load jQuery function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Can anyone please help me to understand, why I'm not able to load my jQuery functions(stored in script.js) using HTML(index.htm)

Following are the codes of:

script.js

```js
$.get("./Components/head.htm", function(data) {
  $("head").append(data);
});

$("#logo").on("error", function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $("#name").show();
});

$("#search").keyup(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>SAM</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="brand">
      <img src="./Static/Logo.png" id="logo">
      <h1 hidden id="name">SAM Store</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="search" id="search" list="suggest">
      <datalist id="suggest">
                    <option value="Laptop"></option>
                    <option value="Mouse"></option>
                    <option value="Keyboard"></option>
                    <option value="Speaker"></option>
                    <option value="Earphone"></option>
                </datalist>
    </div>
    <script>
    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[N.B.: Functions are working if I'm adding $.get function in index.htm and importing script.js using it, but they are not working if I'm referencing script.js on index.htm & importing $.get function. Also, the browser is successfully able to load the script.js in both of these cases]

Comment: Try wrapping your actions to dom-ready function. Now you add `$("#search").keyup` on element that does not exist yet

Comment: You load jquery twice, does that have a reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ever you use jquery always load the code inside an on ready statement, otherwise they will not always load on time.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $.get("Components/head.htm", function(data) {
    $("head").append(data);
  });

  $("#logo").on("error", function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#name").show();
  });

  $("#search").keyup(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });

});
```

Comment: Hi @advertmanagerpro.com, the solution worked, but I'm still not able to understand if the issue was arising because script.js was not getting loaded, then why was chrome showing that script.js is loaded, also if I'm moving the script-src syntax of script.js in index.htm to head.htm(the file which is being loaded by $.get function), and instead of it, if I'm moving $.get function, why was the jquery functions working?

Comment: If you do not use $(document).ready() then sometimes the javascript will be executed before the html is loaded to the page. When you use $(document).ready() it tells javascript to wait until all html is fully loaded into the DOM Memory before it will run the javascript code. The html always needs to be loaded into the DOM Memory before the javascript/jquery can find the elements, as it searches the DOM Memory to find each element. DOM stands for Document Object Model. Its like the browsers inbuilt memory

Comment: When you do not use $(document).ready() then sometimes the javascript loads at the correct time which is after the html is loaded, and sometimes it loads before the html is fully loaded. it really depends on the javascript file download/open time. $(document).ready() was designed specifically to fix this issue. It tells the browser to wait until all html is loaded and ready before it executes the javascript inside the ready function.

Comment: What I understood is that the functions that I have used in script.js are actually event listeners, which will detect the events whenever they occur. If it is so, then if javascript is getting loaded first, why is it not able to detect the events

Comment: I believe the 'on' function is supposed to detect html at anytime but you are supposed to bind it to the body of the document as a parent element as well as your selected element for that to work but it still relies on the body element being loaded first, yet the other functions all need to be loaded after the html.

Comment: for example this will bind the on function to the body as parent and #logo as child element $( "body" ).on( "click", "#logo", function() {

Comment: Yet in general i would say always use the ready() function or you will get random results. Some functions may work and others may fail randomly when not using it. You can read more about the ready function here - https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Hi advertmanagerpro.com, Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: Sure thats ok, its good to hear you got it working. Good luck with your project :)